# How can I handle a customized tag in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

For example, I have a web page like this:

```
<title>Testing</title> 
<body> 
<a href="print://helloWorld">I am a hyper-link</a> 
</body>
```

In my program, I have a UIWebView, and it will display this web site, when the user click the "I am a hyper-link", I would like the console, to print the "helloWorld", how can I do so? Thank you. (Actually, I would like to the UIWebView knows when I click on the "print://" in hyperlink, it will do some callback on my application specify function.)

Comment: See [**my answer on this topic here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516797/how-to-use-javascript-to-communicate-with-objective-c-code/4516865#4516865)

Answer (score 0):

You add a URL handler to your info.plist file and then handle the URL in your application delegate.

See this for reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102207

Comment: With my solution, the event can be localized to the `UIWebViewDelegate` only and not application-wide.

Comment: @Jacon - Don't see the difference except that your answer is telling him how to use his URLs. Let the developer decide.

Comment: Spelling error there. :P And of course I agree that it should be the dev's decision.