# Can I link to an HTML file in my project from a UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview

If I load a string containing HTML into a UIWebView, and that string contains  objects (hyperlinks) that are relative to that string, i.e. , where there is some object with id "something," then the link works - click on it and the web view jumps to the referenced object.

What I want is to get  navigation to a different file in my project, in other words as though the path to the different file were a URL.

I have found that if the href IS a URL, such as href="http://www.amazon.com", then the link works.

If I put the name of a file, OR the [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ] of that name, in the href, then the link does not work.

Is there some way I can generate the equivalent of a URL pointing to an HTML file that is in the project, so that an  can link to that HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution at this link:

[How to use Javascript to communicate with Objective-c code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516797/how-to-use-javascript-to-communicate-with-objective-c-code/4516865#4516865)

Essentially, the solution is to implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol's shouldStartLoadWithRequest method, and "trap" a particular value of scheme.  So my links, instead of saying something like:

```
<a href="http://someplace.location">
```

are like:

```
<a href="mylink://#filename.ext">
```

By catching attempts to load anything with scheme "mylink," I can use:

```
[[request URL] fragment]
```

within shouldStartLoadWithRequest, and get the filename.ext.  I then release my previous UIWebView, load in the contents of the specified file, and make that the contents of a new UIWebView.  The effect is that the links work with normal appearance, even though they are being implemented with my code.  I return NO because I don't want the usual loading to take place.  If the scheme is NOT mylink, I can return YES to allow normal operation.

Regrettably, I still have no way to jump TO a fragment within a web view.  In linking to a real URL, you can say something like "www.foo.org#page50" and jump straight to wherever an object on the new page has an id of "page50."  With my method, I can only go to the top of the page.

This is also not going to give me a "go-back" function unless I record the filenames and implement it myself.